# How do I ask a friendly coworker to remind me what their name is?

Tags: communication, colleagues

I have a coworker at my place of work that I am somewhat friendly with. Often times when I pass his desk, we'll both say hi and talk for a couple minutes about this or that. We're not exactly close friends, but it's fun talking to him.

I cannot remember his name.

As far as I can tell, there is nothing at his desk to indicate his name, as many other employees have. Looking at his badge would be too obvious, as badges here are generally attached to belt loops, and I'd have to lean in to get a good look, and that would be extremely weird.

Should I tell this person that I can't remember his name? Would that be insulting to him to say that I've forgotten? Should I just let it go and leave them as Mystery Coworker in my mind? We don't directly work together, so I don't think I would ever *need* to know his name. I'm not sure what the best move is here.

Comment: Related question on IPS: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/4/102.

Comment: Comments are intended to help improve a post or seek clarification. Please don't answer the questions in the comments. These can't be easily voted on as the best answers, and they may inadvertently prevent other users  from providing real answers. Please see [How should I post a useful non-answer if it shouldn't be a comment?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1866/98) for more guidance.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/302/ - Obligatory xkcd comic

Comment: “Oh by the way - I am not sure we have been properly introduced. I’m X  “

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen we had absolutely been properly introduced by that point.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense you could have mentioned that.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Many companies have a list of employees with pictures somewhere. If yours has one (and even if you don't think it does, it might) then that would be a very easy way to figure out the names of your colleagues. Given that it's a very valuable resource for new employees, most companies will try to keep such a list around.

Might help you learn a few other names, too.

(Of course, if your company doesn't have one, this answer isn't very useful to you, but it might be to other people checking this question.)

Comment: Good one! I've used the company employee list more than once.

Comment: Unfortunately, the company I work for is several orders of magnitude too large for this to be feasible. I might be able to track down an employee list for just our group, though. I'll take a look.

Comment: It turns out there was a seat map! I was able to find his name without any awkwardness at all.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense The irony here is that normally such a tool is used because you know the name but not the seat... But I suppose it works the other way around, too.

Comment: Make sure that the seat map is up-to-date ;)

Comment: Yeah.... the seat maps at my workplace are always far out of date. Just further awkwardness.

Comment: No worries, the seat map has images as well. Verified, it is him.

Comment: How about LinkedIn? If your company's on LinkedIn, you can probably see the employees working.

Comment: Or ask for his email, "Let me send you this very cute cat video...". Then you can get your answer from the address book.

Answer (score 260):

The best way to do this without being super awkward is to ask *one of your coworkers* what his name is.

> Hey Bob, do you know the name of the guy that sits in the corner next to Alice? I talk to him all the time but I don't think I ever got his name!

No need to make it super complicated or make a big deal out of it. It happens to everyone.

Comment: yes good suggestion, asking other coworkers is definitely the least awkward way of doing this (seems we answered almost at the same time ha).

Comment: I think, if you phrase it right, you can probably just ask directly (no need to go to co-workers). "Sorry, I'm really terrible with names. What was your name again?"... Sure, do that enough times and it'll label you as "that guy who's terrible with names", but asking co-workers will likely have the same effect in the long run anyway.

Comment: Unless he's the one guy in the office whose always there but no one knows. Spooky.

Comment: @Shaamaan You can do that maybe the second time you're talking to him — at a max the third time maybe. Ages later it would be really awkward https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fN4_NiCIdcw&t=42s

Comment: @anotherdave Well, at that point you risk getting the "bad with names" label anyway. ;) PS. **I'm** bad with names, so I should know! :P

Answer (score 103):

Just say "I'm sorry, I'm really bad with names, could you remind me what your name is?" or something along those lines. Any reasonable person won't be insulted, in fact they'll appreciate you care enough to actually ask.

If they are insulted, then they aren't a reasonable person, so there's not much to do about it in that case. But I've never had a single person react negatively when I've asked to be reminded of their name.

Comment: I don't think he would be *insulted*; it just looks *awkward / weird* to be talking to him for some time without knowing his name (which is usually one of the first things people ask when start socializing).

Comment: Don't worry about looking awkward - I'd say a majority of the daily interactions we have would fall in the "awkward" category.... like when the bagger at the store starts using plastic bags instead of the bags I brought and it's like "er, um, I have bags here"; or the person on the phone asks me to spell my name and they get it wrong 2-3 times (I have an unusual last name, so that happens constantly).... awkwardness is everyday life, so don't worry about it.

Comment: I *am* really bad with names, and have had to do this quite a bit, in the workplace and otherwise. Like @Saguaro, I have never had a negative reaction. +1

Comment: About half the time I confess to forgetting someone's name, they sigh with relief and admit that they forgot my name too. And then we both have a good laugh.

Comment: I had to marry my wife, since I couldn't remember her name! :( "Do you take Meghan as your lawfully wedded wife?"... "Aaaah, it's Meghan... I _knew_ it started with an M".

Comment: My significant other's reaction wasn't exactly positive, but turns out the couch is more comfy than it looks.

Comment: Ditto what @njuffa said. I am the *absolute worst* at remembering names, despite having a great memory in general. I'll remember faces, and can almost always remember where I know someone from and probably details about who they are. Yet I learn names poorly and forget them if I don't use them regularly. I've never had anyone react poorly to my admission of forgetting their name, and even people who look slightly offended by it are rare. And remember, I do this on a regular basis, sometimes with people who I considered friends!

Comment: Get used to doing this. Barring some kind of medical anomaly, if you ask right away whenever you can't remember then you won't ever get into this awkward stage where it's been "too long" to ask.

Comment: Why would you concede you forgot (i.e. look stupid) when you could leave it that it wasn't quite as impressionable has he would have hoped?

Comment: That's pretty judgmental - noted though, if I ever forget your name, I won't ask for fear of being judged "stupid". ;)

Comment: Being up-front is the best answer. The best _technique_ would be to admit to the awkwardness, too. E.g. _"Hey, I realize this is awkward, but could you remind me your name please?"_

Comment: I'm bad enough at remembering people's names that I tend to say so just after being introduced, "Nice meeting all of you. I'm really bad with names, I've probably forgotten yours already. Lets see... Uhh...Ssssteeeeve?" Usually takes me daily use of talking with someone for two weeks before it finally sticks.

Comment: This doesn't work very well if you've been doing this a long time, because it highlights that you DIDN'T care enough to ask them their name eariler.

Comment: It's weird if someone doesn't know your name - I would never admit it past a certain point.  I don't know that I'd be insulted, but I'd probably be a little hurt if someone I talked to a lot asked me my name!  Better to ask someone else who knows the person.

Answer (score 20):

I have been at both ends of this situation on several occasions. I just go with, "I'm sorry, I forgot your name." The other person instantly provides their name, and we move on to the business. I do the same when my name is forgotten.

Don't make the solution more complicated than the problem. Don't go bothering *other* people to remind you, don't go asking for emails. It is common for people to forget names. A lot of people don't even remember the names of movie stars and other celebrities.

Comment: Just keep calling the guy "Newman" and eventually he'll correct you.

Comment: "I do the same when my name is forgotten." What do you do when it is your name and it is so masked you cannot see it?

Comment: @MichaelKaras Then I just say, "My name is Uchiha Madara". Nobody asks me any further questions. :)

Answer (score 12):

If you are not sure about his name you could try discreetly asking *other* coworkers about it, so it does not create a possibly awkward situation by asking that person directly.

How that person may take it really depends on his personality, but if you ask politely I see no problem in asking him directly, as you say you are on good terms with each other. Again, not sure if he knows your name or if you salute yourselves with it, but how he takes it strongly depends on him.

You could also try, as an alternative, asking that person for his company email. Usually those email accounts are something like "lastname.name@company.com", so you could infer his name from that information.

Comment: Even better, ask him to email you something. You'll get his email (which will have parts of his name in it), his name as his email client sees it, and probably a name in an email signature.

Comment: yes good suggestion :) it is highly probable it has its signature there

Comment: But then he'll have to admit he doesn't know @TheSoundDefense's name, and hence doesn't know his/her email address.

Comment: @Thierry I'm not sure I understand your point here. I'm assuming you mean TheSoundDefense would have to admit he doesn't know his coworker's name, since the opposite isn't really a problem. Most companies can't *quite* do "lastname.name@company.com" format, since there's often a little name overlap (especially since OP has said `...the company I work for is several orders of magnitude too large for [looking up the employee's picture] to be feasible`). It usually ends up "lastname.name<number>@company.com" or something, so asking for an email doesn't necessarily mean they don't know their name.

Comment: "Their name; what who that person over there?", said loudly with a pointing finger.  Arghhhh.  This has happened to me!

Comment: @LordFarquaad I was merely implying that perhaps the person whose name is unkown to TheSoundDefense, does not know TheSoundDefense's name either.

Comment: @LordFarquaad I query our "contact list" to find people of I don't recall their name all the time, and that's has 18,000 entries, half of them who don't have a picture uploaded. But I restrict my searches to office buildings, departments, position and team. Or search with just a fraction of the name. Large number of employees doesn't mean searching has to be impossible.

Comment: TheSoundDefense could ask the target to email it to their non-work address, which presumably they'd have to give him.

Comment: @Abigail I never said it was. I was just saying there's a point where a company is too big to use "firstname-lastname" type emails; there's some overlap with names (maybe there's two John Smiths), so asking someone their email address doesn't imply you don't know their name. OP saying the company is too big to look up an employee's picture just supports the fact that their company is probably big enough to have reached that point.

Answer (score 6):

**Just ask**. Showing an interest in a person is pretty much automatically flattering. Unless you are constantly forgetting their name most folks will be pleased that you are going to the effort to learn/remember theirs. Once they tell you, be sure to say it again at least twice in that conversation and try and use it again a time or two in future conversations.

> Hey, how's it going. Look, I'm kind of embarrassed to admit it, but the longer I leave it the more embarrassing it will get so I'm going to go ahead and just admit I've forgotten your name.

> > My name's Bob, it is kind of a common name.
>
> Good to "meet" you again Bob. I'm sure you remembered my name was @TheSoundDefense right, ha ha ha.

> > Oh yes... Of course. *Embarrassed Smile*
> > Alright, I should get back to work. See you around Bob.

Comment: Seriously! It's not really all that awkward. You might be embarrassed that you can't remember a name (or maybe were never told), but when you ask they will most likely smile/laugh and all will be fine!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to simply asking (which I've done, just said "Oh man, I just totally blanked on your name, I'm so sorry!" - only to find out they didn't know my name either! We were both a little embarrassed) you can also offer to send them an email then ask how they spell their name so you can make sure they get it. It looks a little contrived if you don't *actually* have something to send, but if you do it could work like this:

> I just saw the most hilarious video of Spongebob singing Black Sabbath's War Pigs! I'll send you the link, um, but I don't think your in my contact list. How do you spell your name again, y'know, just to make sure I send it to the right person?

Comment: This will sound very weird if their name is easy to spell.

Comment: @Erik: Yes, there is that risk. But you can save grace by saying, "Oh, I thought you spelled it ${OBSCURE_SPELLING}". Or you could just adming "Oh, I thought your name was something else". It's a little embarrassing, but most people seem to take this OK. I've yet to see anyone get seriously offended by something like that. Maybe I've been lucky in having easy-going co-workers...

Comment: You spell it B-O-B? Oh gosh, I thought it was B-A-H-B! :)

Comment: @DonBranson: But at least you'd still get their name!

Comment: Indeed. I know that's what would happen to me, too. :)

Comment: You spell it A-L? Oh I thought it was A-H-L-L-H

Comment: If he has a common name, there will probably be several ones on the company. so you may need a surname (which you may not be expected to know), or he could be bob5@company.com

Comment: Do this the other way around then? "Hey, remember when we talked about [random subject] and you said you knew a great location to do [kayaking/hiking/dancing/whatever].... do you mind sending me the details in an email?"

Comment: Oh, I knew your name was Bob ... I, well, I forgot what your last name was so asked how to spell it to cover my embarrassment. I totes new your name was Bob, and this whole convoluted thing wasn't a clever ploy to figure out what your name was. Nope.

Comment: @Patrice: Oh that's a good one too. And if *they* don't know *your* name then they have to find a way to figure it out. This could get messy... ;)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner lol... I can see the response.. "sure... but do you mind sending me that other article first?" "NO YOU GO FIRST!!"

Answer (score 4):

1. Next time you walk by his desk and he's not there, look at the phone on his desk.  If it has an LCD display on it, it might show his name.  If not, it will probably show his phone number.
2. Memorize the last 4 or however many digits you need to make an intraoffice call.
3. When you know he's not at his desk, call his number and wait for his voicemail.  (You'll probably want to make the call from a conference room phone so that his phone doesn't tell him he has a missed call from you.)
4. Hopefully he will have customized his voicemail greeting to say his name.

Comment: If you can find out the person's extension from your steps 1 & 2, there might be a phone directory you could peruse to find out the name, too. Preferably one that's online so you can ctrl+F for the number. ;)

Answer (score 3):

First thing I tell people upon meeting them is often that I'm bad at remembering names. But I refuse to be embarrassed about it -- "I hate to admit this, but I seem to have forgotten your name again" is an entirely reasonable statement.

If it bothers you more than it does me, it is possible to train yourself to be better at this skill; those who need it professionally (salesmen, teachers, etc.) do so. I've seen someone recite back 30 names at the end if an icebreaker name-mnemonic game ("my name is George and I like Grapes"), and that's learned rather than innate.

Answer (score 2):

There are already great answers, and I for one would simply ask him again. 
But I also have an additional way of re-retrieving the name if you don't want to ask him directly: Find something that might interest/entertain him on the internet. Then ask him for his mail address, because you'd like to send him something interesting. Depending on the topic, you may first start a conversation about that topic and then tell him you have an interesting/funny thing to show him and ask for his contact details. Alternatively, you can ask for a chat account or similar, if your company manages something like that.

Of course, you are out of luck if your company mail addresses do not include the full name, but you would know that from your own beforehand to decide if this approach can work for you.

Also, first you might think about whether he may have already sent you a mail. In that case it's easy, just dig out that mail and hopefully you have his name.

Also, our company has a floor plan at the entrance and each room has pictures and names at the door - maybe you have something similar and overlooked it so far?

There are also two very culture depending options I've seen (also dependent on your character):

1. If he shares an office with you, ask your colleagues if you can take a picture with them - as you like to collect them / show your family who you work with, then print it out and have them sign it.
2. If he doesn't share an office and you don't have a floor plan, simply draw one yourself and let it go around - ask your colleagues to fill it out, each with their own name. That way you get all the names and they may even pick up the idea and ask you to hang it in the floor somewhere so all new guys have the benefit of it.

Comment: Sounds too planned.  I prefer the "don't make a big deal out of it" type answers.

Comment: @HankCa Me too, (except maybe for the email approach which might just fit if you have anything to send him anyway), but these are some things I've seen and I added them as suggestions for people that don't feel like asking (again).

Comment: That is a *looooot* of effort just to find out someone's name.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if your company has a workplace chat or messaging app.

What I've done a few times is put eyes on my coworker as they approached their desk in the morning. Then once I saw the "John McJonathan has logged in" message, I had a good idea of their name. Of course, I'd want to do this two or three times before I was convinced that was actually them.

It also works as they're leaving, but it's a little harder to keep track of "John McJonathan has logged out" and then see your coworker leave, since you aren't really sure what name you're looking for.

I'd try to do it in the mornings if you can.

Answer (score 1):

One I always use is hey what was your name again? When they respond say "Opps I mean your surname!". Since surnames are more often forgotten it is not awkward at all.

This works because most people don't introduce themselves with their last names, also you generally just work first-name basis.

Comment: This reads more as a comment than an answer.  Can you elaborate as to why this is the right approach?

Comment: It's an answer because it provides a way of obtaining the name without it being too awkward.

Comment: @JaneS what is particularly troublesome is it merely repeats [prior answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/100975/168) that was posted 5 hours before. I could understand a repetition if it was somehow better presented or explained but this doesn't look like the case here. OP seems to completely ignore guidance to [Back It Up and Don't Repeat Others](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255/168)

Comment: @MaskedMan Hahahaha now that would be awkward. In many ways at once. Especially because I can't think of any escape at all.

Comment: @gnat gj you linked a meta post on my first answer here :| think about it.

Comment: @gnat also I didn't see that answer and I still can't find it.

Comment: Someone did that to me once "what's your full name?" but it was so out of context and unnecessary that it was obvious what they were doing.

Answer (score -4):

If you are certain the person comes from another country, especially if it's one where a different language is used, you can ask "How do you pronounce your name? I just want to be sure I say it right." This comes with a slight risk, and you may then have to think on your feet. For instance, if you are working together in an English-speaking country and they look at you quizzically and say "It's Michael", you might say "Yes I know, but I wanted to make sure I got the L sound exactly right."

Comment: I don't see an issue with covering yourself by asking leading questions when you have forgotten someone's name but I tend to solve that problem by either asking a common associate or just being honest by saying "I'm so sorry but I forgot your name" and then reintroducing myself if it seems appropriate.